# Pandas DataFrame from txt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a .txt that goes like this:

```
       USA

Arizona - New Mexico
Interstate 40
Interstate 10

South Dakota - Minneapolis
Interstate 90

South Carolina - Washington

Arizona - California
Interstate 40
Interstate 10
Interstate 8

    ANOTHER COUNTRY

State A - State B
Highway 1
Highway 2
Highway 3
...
...
```

I want to create a DataFrame and a CSV in pandas, where the first column contains the States, and the second column the Highway.

```
      States                    HW_Number
Arizona - New Mexico          Interstate 40
Arizona - New Mexico          Interstate 10
South Dakota - Minneapolis    Interstate 90
Arizona - California          Interstate 40
Arizona - California          Interstate 10
Arizona - California          Interstate 9
State A - State B             Highway 1
State A - State B             Highway 2
State A - State B             Highway 3
```

How can I manage to do that? Not all the states have the same amount of Highways, and can have 0 Highways, and those that have 0, I do not want to be integrated in the DataFrame.

A column with the Country could be integrated as well.

Thank you

Comment: It will be very easy to set up rules.  If the line has one word, it's a country.  If it has a dash, it'a pair of cities.  Otherwise, it's a highway.

Comment: If you're happy with the answers, please consider accepting one of them

Answer (score 0):

As I said, a pretty easy file to parse:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = []
state = None
for line in open('x.txt'):
    if line[0] == ' ':
        continue
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    if '-' in line:
        state = line
    else:
        rows.append( (state,line) )

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['state','road'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
----------
                        state           road
0        Arizona - New Mexico  Interstate 40
1        Arizona - New Mexico  Interstate 10
2  South Dakota - Minneapolis  Interstate 90
3        Arizona - California  Interstate 40
4        Arizona - California  Interstate 10
5        Arizona - California   Interstate 8
6           State A - State B      Highway 1
7           State A - State B      Highway 2
8           State A - State B      Highway 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the rows and use characteristics of your structured data to create lists. These lists can be used to make a dataframe or series.

1. read the lines from the file into a list (f.readlines())
2. remove empty rows
3. keep track of current state (doesn't end with a number)
4. append the states and highways to lists
5. use lists to make a dataframe or series

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import io
f = io.StringIO(
    """
USA

Arizona - New Mexico
Interstate 40
Interstate 10

South Dakota - Minneapolis
Interstate 90

South Carolina - Washington

Arizona - California
Interstate 40
Interstate 10
Interstate 8

ANOTHER COUNTRY

State A - State B
Highway 1
Highway 2
Highway 3
    """
)
lines = f.readlines()
states = []
hw_numbers = []
current_state = None
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip() #removes \n
    
    if line == '': #remove empty rows
        continue
    elif line[-1].isdigit() == False: #if not a digit, then it's a state
        current_state = line
    else: #if it is a digit, then it's a highway
        states.append(current_state)
        hw_numbers.append(line)
pd.DataFrame({
    'States':states,
    'HW_number':hw_numbers
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your solution. Very well explained! It worked really well, and i will apply this strategy in the future.